# regular expression missing pattern

Tags: php, regex

I try to create a regex (PHP) that allow all digits,and allow only closed brackets with [digit-digit] format for exp.

```
0[1-3]xxx xx //valid
[1-3]xxx xx //valid
05[1-3]xxx xx //valid
0[1-3]555 6789 //valid
0332 555 6789 //valid

0[1-11]xxx xx //not valid
[1-3]xxxa xx //not valid
```

My regex pattern, `[0-9]?\[[0-9]-[0-9]\][0-9 x]+`, validates the following:

```
[0-5]212xxx xx xx
[0-5]212xx xx xx
[0-5]212xx xx xx
```

...but it does not validate this string:

```
1231232131
```

Change regex completely or edit the regex already but it seems getting complicated. How can I achieve my goal with most efficient way?

Comment: Try: `/^\d*(\[\d-\d\])?[\dx\s]+$/`

Comment: @Thamilan thanks but couldnt catch [0-5] of [0-5]212xxx xx xx string

Comment: @TyForHelpDude It is catching: https://eval.in/582657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern tests that string contains digit, construction `[digit-digit]`, space and character `x`

```
 ^(\d|\[\d-\d\]|x| )+$
```

or you can write it so:

```
^([\dx ]|\[\d-\d\])+$
```

[demo and explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/yP3jV3/2)

Comment: what about x characters try this: [0-5]212xxx xx xx

Comment: i've written another variant of regex. You can use any of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113734/discussion-between-tyforhelpdude-and-splash58).